# Склонение числительных

Tags: числительные

Прослоняйте, пожалуйста,    Как верно? Именительный: Сто семьдесят шесть двести шетьдесят вторая доля или сто семьдесят шесть шестьдесят "вторых доля" или "вторая доля", или "вторых долей". Как в других падежах?

Comment: Вы бы задание целиком написали! У Вас где-то ошибка. Может, Сто семьдесят шесть целых двести шестьдесят две тысячных доли? Или как-то по-другому?

Comment: Это доля в комнате. Всего площадь 26,2 кв.метра, из них мои 17,6 кв.м и получается у меня 176/262 доли или долей- так записано в свидетельстве оправе собственноти Вообще как склонять? Продал сто семьдесят шесть(ую) двести шестьдесят вторых(ую) доли (долю)(долей). Или мне принадлежит......доля (ли)( лей)

Comment: проще продать, чем просклонять

Comment: 26,2 - это площадь комнаты или квартиры? Впрочем, это никак не скажется на склонении. Просто для понимания.  

***Продал сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторых долей [комнаты].***

Comment: Для понимания-это человек, который продал мне долю имел две комнаты площадью 26,2 кв.м, мне он продал одну комнату площадью 17,6 кв.м, теперь у меня в документах написано, что мне принадлежит 176/262 доли.

Comment: Тогда вам принадлежит *сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторых дол**ей** **квартиры***.  Видимо, ошибка распространенная, коли мы уж тут договориться не можем. Но я буду отстаивать именно свое понимание. Если хотите, можете посмотреть  этот вопрос на "Грамоте". 
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4316
Там даже юристы есть... Они еще больше в курсе.

Comment: Смотрим, как записано:"...у меня 176/262 доли или долей""- всё правильно  записано в свидетельстве: 176/262(вторых) от всей доли-читаем так, как дробь в математике, 176/262 долей - 176 из двухсот шестидесяти двух долей -читаем, как в экономике-юриспруденции, а в разговорной речи происходит контаминация значений, легче прочитать как дробь, вот и читается "...вторых долей", но это не норма(достались же не ...вторые доли, а часть от ...вторых), а разговорное, или что-то вроде профессионализма, как дОговор,а ваш форум на Грамоте такой же, как у нас, Справка Вам так и не ответила.

Comment: Людмила не надо смотреть, как записано. Вы неправильно это понимаете.
Смотрите, что СКАЗАНО: в квартире мне принадлежат 17,6 метра из 26,2 метра.
Ну что еще надо-то? Это и есть ***дробь***. 

>а в разговорной речи происходит контаминация значений, легче прочитать как дробь,  

Вот у Вас что-то подобное и произошло.Никакого профессионализма тут не надо. Элементарная грамотность и понимание русского языка. На столе лежит четыре яблока. Я взял два. Я взял половину **яблока** или половину **яблок**?   
В квартире 262 ***доли***. Мне принадлежат 176 **доли** или **долей**? О чем спор-то?

Comment: Половина-существительное, а не числительное, пример некорректен. Существительное (доли)сочетается на правах управления не числителя, а знаменателя в Им. п., а в других падежах согласуется.Вам принадлежат не просто 176 долей, а от двухсот шестидесяти двух частей всей доли.

Answer (score 1):

У порядковых числительных (составных) склоняется только последнее слово. Но такого числительного, как у вас, не можкт быть: 176262. Это сто семьдесят шесть  тысяч двести шестьдесят вторая доля в им. падеже.                                              
     Р. п. сто семьдесят шесть тысяч двести шестьдесят второй доли
Д. п. сто семьдесят шесть тысяч двести шестьдесят второй доле
В. п. сто семьдесят шесть тысяч двести шестьдесят вторую долю
Т. п. сто семьдесят шесть тысяч двести шестьдесят второй долей
П. п. о сто семьдесят шесть тысяч двести шестьдесят второй доле

Comment: Не 176262, а 176/262

Answer (score 1):

Да, это вопрос столетия!
*Штирлиц знал, как склоняется  176/262, он догадывался, что об этом знает Мюллер, но не мог представить, что думают об этом в Центре.*

Но тем не менее - склонять можно.
Числитель склоняется как количественное, знаменатель - как порядковое числительное.

И. сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторых долей
Р. ста семидесяти шести двести шестьдесят вторых долей
Д. ста семидесяти шести двести шестьдесят вторым долям
В. сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторых долей
Т. ста семидесятью шестью двести шестьдесят вторыми долями
П. (о)ста семидесяти шести двести шестьдесят вторых долях

В именительном может встретиться еще разговорный вариант по типу
И. сто семьдесят две (три, четыре) двести шестьдесят втор**ых** доли  
но он обычно ограничен в употреблении знаменателями, меньшими сотни.

Пардон, там в числителе "шесть", не "две". Тогда да - в именительном - ***вторых долей***. 
Поправил.

//--------------------------

Поскольку совершенно на ровном месте возникло непонимание...

У меня 1/6 квартир**ы** (машины, дачи, метра, яблока). - У меня 1/6 дол**я** (часть) [квартиры, машины, дачи, метра, яблока].

У меня 2/6 квартир**ы** (машины, дачи, метра, яблока). - У меня 2/6 дол**и** (части) [квартиры, машины, дачи, метра, яблока].

У меня 5/6 квартир**ы** (машины, дачи, метра, яблока). - У меня 5/6 дол**ей** (частей) [квартиры, машины, дачи, метра, яблока].

У меня пять шестых квартир**ы** (машины, дачи, метра, яблока). - У меня пять шестых дол**ей** (частей) [квартиры, машины, дачи, метра, яблока].

Не надо путать. Если из квартиры площадью 26,2 кв. м мне принадлежит  17,6 кв метра,
то мне принадлежит ровно 176/262 квартиры. А не какой-то "доли" этой квартиры.
А моя часть в ней - 176/262 долей.
***Сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторых долЕЙ.***   
И никак иначе.

И. ***Мне принадлежит сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторые долей [комнаты].***

Р. ***Собственник ста семидесяти шести двести шестьдесят вторых долей [комнаты].***

Д. ***Присматриваюсь к ста семидесяти шести двести шестьдесят вторым долям [комнаты].***

В. ***Продал сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторых долей [комнаты].***

Т. ***Распоряжаюсь принадлежащими мне ста семьюдесятью шестью двести шестьдесят вторыми долями [комнаты]***

П. ***Прописан на принадлежащих мне ста семидесяти шести двести шестьдесят вторых долях [комнаты]***

Не знаю, как еще объяснить...

> "шестьдесят вторые долей [комнаты]"-совсем не по-русски,

По-русски, не извольте сомневаться. "Шесть (каких-то там) дол**и**" - вот это не по-русски.

[[@Людмила](/users/247/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0)](/users/247/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0) !!!
//------------
Не надо меня так "править". )))
Вот, кстати, почему я всегда за то, что на опечатки надо указывать. Видно в чем заблуждается указывающий.  )))

Себя я прекрасно понял. Вас, кстати, тоже. 
Вы не понимаете, что кто-то может иметь две доли, три доли и т.д. Поэтому настаивате, что речь идет только о части доли. Отсюда и единственное число в падежах.
А доля - она как часть. Можно разделить добычу на десять долей (каждая доля тогда ьудет "десятой") - и отдать атаману две доли. Или три. Тогда у атамана - три десятых долей. А не **три десятых доли.

Поверьте, с квартирой, т.е. с метрами - то же самое.

> Половина-существительное, а не числительное, пример некорректен.

Людмила, я здесь не обсуждаю, какая часть речи "половина", хотя могу поспорить и с этим. "Одна вторая" там. Тоже придеретесь?

Можете, наконец, ответить, что Вам не нравится в логике?

*Есть апельсин. В нем шесть долек. Я взял **две** дольки. Я взял 1/3 долек или 1/3 дольки?* 
Одна долька - это одна доля апельсина.
Пока не ответите "долек" или "дольки" дальше не пойдем.

//-----------------------------------------------------------

## Со "Справки"

//-----------------------------------------------------------
Вопрос № 271499     
Здравствуйте,
подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно склонять составные числительные, а также согласовать дробь с существительным "доля" (или "доли", множ.число?) в данном случае:
"Имущество состоит из 21/85 (двадцатИ одной восЬМИДЕСЯТИ пятых) долИ квартиры"
Спасибо!

Нусильда

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Верно: ...из двадцати **одной восемьдесят пятой доли**.
*Числитель дроби — это количественное числительное (двадцать один), а знаменатель — порядковое (восемьдесят пятый). Слово доля стоит в форме единственного числа, так как относится к числительному, которое заканчивается на один.*

//------------------------------

Вопрос № 270713

1/4 доля (или доли) земельного участка, расположенная (или расположенного) по адресу...
Спасибо!
ksuusha

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Верно: **1/4 доля участка**, расположенного...

//------------------------------

Вопрос № 260447

Добрый день!
Вопрос о склонении дробных числительных в деловой документации.
"...о продаже 1/5 от 7/128 долИ/долЕЙ..."
"...владеет 2/5 от 7/128 долЯМИ/долЕЙ..."
Какие окончания правильные?
kovaleva-sv

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
В обоих случаях верно: **долей**.

//------------------------------

http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%E4%EE%EB%FF

Конечно, это не прямой ответ на мой вопрос (коего я, видимо, уже не дождусь), но если немного поднапрячься - и сделать обобщение...

Comment: Все понятно, только в И.вторых долей? Как в верхней строчке.

Comment: Ситуация тупиковая, как у Штирлица.

Comment: Да, в именительном у меня "...шесть  ...вторых долЕЙ". 
Потому, что их **шесть** долей. Как **шесть** бел**ых** мыш**ей**. Или ***шесть** ядовит**ых** **змей**.  

>Ситуация тупиковая, как у Штирлица.  
  
Спокойно, мы вас не бросим.

Comment: А теперь посмотрите, что у Вас на самом деле написано:"шестьдесят вторые долей [комнаты]"-совсем не по-русски, вот Вас и поправили, а Вы не видите своей опечатки в И.п..Действительно тупик.Никого не хотите понять и даже себя.

Comment: У меня-то по русски. 
А вот у вас - "по понятиям". 
ответил в тексте.

Answer (score 1):

У меня 176/262 произносится " сто семьдесят шесть из двухсот шестидесяти двух долей" Это не чистая дробь, как в математике. Продал сто семьдесят шесть из двухсот шестидесяти двух долей. Или" мне принадлежит сто семьдесят шесть из двухсот шестидесяти двух долей"

Но если нужно прочитать как числительное, то:

И. сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторых доли - дробь управляет родительным падежом ЕДИНСТВЕННОГО числа сущ.

"Мне принадлежит сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторых доли" ,

"Я говорю о ста семидесяти шести двести шестьдесят вторых доли"

Comment: >И. сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторых доли - дробь управляет родительным падежом ЕДИНСТВЕННОГО числа сущ.  
  
Почему родительным? 
И почему "не чистая математика"?
А в косвенных падежах?

"две зеленые доли?" или "две зеленых доли?"

>"Я говорю о ста семидесяти шести двести шестьдесят вторых доли"  
  
Эх, Людмила... не ожидамши я от вас (((
Я говорю ***о долях***. А Вы? 
Или это опечатка?

>" сто семьдесят шесть из двухсот шестидесяти двух долей"   
  
"две третьих" однако, а "не две (из) трех".

У меня это как "176 зеленых долей" или "176 больших долей"

Comment: Потому что в именительном( вин.) падеже- управление, а в остальных согласование.  http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=2.15   http://tepka.ru/rozental_2/166.html
8. Правильными являются конструкции 35,5 процента (не ...процентов), 12,6 километра (не ...километров), т.е. при смешанном числе существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число. Также: 45,0 (сорок пять и ноль десятых) секунды, 67/8 (шесть и семь восьмых) метра и т.п.

Comment: Не чистая математика, потому что :http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0
 знак «косая черта» применяется в научной и деловой речи.
Он употребляется в следующих функциях: 
1.В функции, близкой к союзам и и или, как знак альтернативности понятий или обозначения единого сложного понятия, напр.: .
2.Для обозначения отношения каких-либо  параметров (цена/качество)
3.В сокращённых обозначениях составных единиц измерения, напр.: ц/га (центнер на гектар), об/мин (оборот в минуту).Вот и здесь 2 из 3 долей=2/3 доли

Comment: Людмила, я так понимаю, вопрос о форме числительного, а не о существительного. 
Существительное здесь "доля", с ней все понятно.
А вот с формой числительного наблюдаются колебания.
"Две больших ягоды" или "две большие ягоды?"
Точно также "Две третьих (доли)" или "Две третьих (доли)".

Вы не ответили и не поправили:
>"Я говорю о ста семидесяти шести двести шестьдесят вторых доли"  
  
Это опечатка?

Comment: Это экономический термин, знак "косая черта" заменяет предлог, а какой - это по ситуации, здесь подойдёт "ИЗ". Так что зря Ваше  "не ожидамши", и это не опечатка, а практика лингвиста в отличие от Вашей математической.

Comment: Где опечатка? Вот Ваш ответ:" П. (о)ста семидесяти шести двести шестьдесят вторых долях". Я поправила только на ед.ч. - "доли", а не "долей" по правилам р.языка.А это вообще не поняла:"Точно также "Две третьих (доли)" или "Две третьих (доли)"- в чём разница, о чём Вы? Кстати, так же - раздельно.

Comment: Людмила права. А ответ на вопрос содержится уже в первом абзаце, еще до уточнения автора.

Comment: >Людмила права. 

В чем??? Уточните.  

>Это экономический термин, знак "косая черта"    
  
Это дробь, Людмила. Простая. С числителем и значменателем. "У меня 176/262 квартиры". А не 176/262 доли.   

Давайте от печки.

***У меня - "1/6 доля кватриры" или  "1/6 доли кватриры"?***

Comment: Меня совсем запутали, все-таки доли или долей?

Comment: Все-таки доли или долей?

Comment: >Все-таки доли или долей? 
  
Мы пока между собой спорим. Бывает.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с behemothus. Дополню объяснение.

Дробное числительное строится ОСОБЫМ СПОСОБОМ. Рассмотрим, например: пять шестых долей  предмета - о пяти шестых долях предмета.

1) числитель "пять" управляет существительным "долей" (пять долей) в И.-В. и согласуется с ним в Д. Т. П. падежах (о пяти долях).

2)Существительное "долей, долях" в любой форме задает Р.п. существительному "предмет"

3) Знаменатель "шестых, шестым" фактически является  ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕМ к существительному "долей" и согласуется с ним во всех падежах. При решении задачи его удобно "пропустить" - получится о пяти (шестых) долях предмета.

Понятие "дробь управляет существительным не совсем корректно: дробь это не "единое число", а словосочетание, поэтому там грамматические связи реализуются последовательно.

4) В бытовой речи существительное "долей" обычно пропускается и получается: пять шестых предмета - о пяти шестых предмета.

В нашем случае получается:сто семьдесят шесть (двести шестьдесят вторых) долей, о ста семидесяти шести (двести шестьдесят вторых) долях".

ОТВЕТ 2. Извините за неточное выражение: согласна я, разумеется, не лично с behemothus, а с тем, как он просклонял дробное числительное. Хотя и он мне очень симпатичен, как и другие участники форума.

ЕЩЕ ОДНО ПОЯСНЕНИЕ
Я полагаю, что  разные решения объясняются именно тем, что грамматика построения дробного числительного  в учебниках не рассматривается и всеми понимается по-разному. В нашем примере:
Сто семьдесят шесть двести шестьдесят вторых (частей) доли – это, действительно, 1/276 от какой-то НЕИЗВЕСТНОЙ ДОЛИ.  Значит, это не выражение другого смысла, а просто ошибочная структура. Правильный смысл  (разделить предмет на 262 части и взять 176 частей) заключен в неправильную форму, которая этот смысл ИСКАЖАЕТ. А причина всего – НЕПРАВИЛЬНОЕ ПОНИМАНИЕ ГРАММАТИКИ ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫХ. Еще раз хочу заострить внимание уважаемых коллег на то, как строится числительное (согласны ли вы с этим?:

А) Дробь как единое целое не управляет существительным, так как является грамматическим словосочетанием.

Б) Управляет существительным (или согласуется с ним) числитель дроби, которое ведет себя как обычное количественное числительное (управление и согласование БЕЗ УЧЕТА ЗНАМЕНАТЕЛЯ):   сто семьдесят шесть  долей -  о ста семидесяти шести долях

В) А КАКИХ долей?  Двести шестьдесят вторых. Знаменатель дроби  – это  грамматическое определение между числительным и существительным, например: пять (каких?) долей → пять шестых долей.

Comment: А теперь почитайте Валгину:В синтаксическом отношении дробные числительные отличаются следующими особенностями:
1) выступают в роли количественного определения 
2) сочетаются с именами существительными ВСЕГДА ПО СПОСОБУ УПРАВЛЕНИЯ, причем существительное употребляется как в единственном, так и во множественном числе (ср. три четвертых комнаты, одна шестая суток- в ед.ч.сутки  не употр.);
http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/index.html?part-086.htm#i5963

Comment: И вот ещё:  дробные числительные типа две пятых (подразумеваются доли единицы)представляют собой имеющие количественное значение сочетания слов (часто с союзом и ), относящихся к разным частям речи, сущ. при таком сочетании слов всегда имеет форму род. п. ед. ч. (слова типа сутки – род. п. мн. ч.): пять десятых участка, три пятых суток; пяти десятым участка, трем пятым суток » [Русская грамматика–1980, т. 1, с. 574]. http://russia-sng.iphil.ru/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=76&Itemid=31&limit=1&limitstart=2

Comment: И я согласна с Валгиной, а не с behemothus, а Вы - как хотите.Мы сами себе выбираем авторитетов.

Comment: Бегемотус тоже согласен с Валгиной.
Он не согласен с Людмилой. С тем как она Валгину толкуют. 
У Валгиной нет ничего на этот случай - использовния не "доли целого", а "доли целых".

>пять десятых участка, три пятых суток; пяти десятым участка, трем пятым суток   

Не наш случай. У нас не один "участок" а 262. 
И принадлежит нам не ***доля участка***, а ***доли***, выражаемые в участках.   
Человек скупил 176 из 262 них. У него 176/262 общего число участк**ов**. А не 176/262 (от одного) участка.

Comment: В смысл вдумайтесь. "176/262 доли" в квартире это 176/162 от десятой части квадратного метра. "Чуть больше одной двадцатой метра". Вы серьезно полагаете, что речь об этом?

Людмила, Вы принципиально против конструкции "взял одну третью долек"? Признаете "только одну третью дольки"?
Можете ответить без Валгиной?

//--------------  

София, вопрос-то не в том, как строится дробное числительное. В том, как понимать "доля". Людмила настаивает, что там дробная часть доли. А я понимаю, что долей этих много - и дроби берутся от этого "много", а не от единичной доли. Смысловая разница огромная.

Comment: > Не наш случай. У нас не один "участок" а 262.

Да всё это наши случаи, только слегка иначе построенные. 
"Пять десятых участка" — это компакт, который в развороте имеет значение "пять тех долей, которые образуются при математическом делении величины участка, то есть площади, на десять". Аналог-но, "у меня есть 176 долей при задании единичной доли путём математ-го деления на 262". Тот же (!) родительный падеж мн. числа; только в этом случае дробь абстрагирована от сущности какого-либо предмета, а *доля* представляет собой здесь аксиоматический атом, заданный единицей измерения.

Comment: >Да всё это наши случаи, только слегка иначе построенные  
  
"Наш случай" - это то, что у автора вопроса.  

Говорил бы он о ста семидесяти шести **целых** и, скажем, одной десятой **доли** - все было бы верно. Но 176/262 **доли** не катит по здаваому смыслу. Это пять с чем-то там **сотых метра**. Вывают такие комнаты?

Comment: Вы принципиально против конструкции "взял одну третью долек"? 
Принимаю только  как разговорное и не как дробь, а как неполное предложение от "взял одну третью часть всех долек" . Об этом и говорится в самом конце  в последней ссылке.

Comment: >Принимаю только как разговорное и не как дробь, 
  
Тогда нам придется прекратить. Ибо это основополагающее понятие при разделе долей. 

Любой юрист скажет, что такое "раздел в равных долях". Или еще каких.

>а как неполное предложение от "взял одну третью часть всех долек"  
  
Это Вы уже решайте, полное оно или неполное. У спрашивающего явно имеется ввиду, что от всех. Потому как размер доли явно не указан. А был бы указан, то получилось бы, что доля равно 1/10 квадратного  метра. И у владельца явно не 176/262 от этого нового платка, а полноценная комната в 17.6 метров.

Comment: Последнее.
Посмотрел сейчас несколько судебных решений - везде 1/4, 1/2, 1/3  - (и т.д.) *доля* в таком-то имуществе. 
Людмила, уверяю Вас, это не от неграмотности. Это от правильного понимания ситуации. Не "долю" они делят. А делят "в долях". 
А все что у Валгиной - там делят метры или сутки. А не что-то "выражаемое в метрах".

Comment: Занятный спор