# Склонение математических дробей

Tags: склонение

Как правильно: *как правопреемника в одной пятой долИ или долЕ, в трех пятых долях или долей?* Где можно найти правила склонения?

Answer (score 3):

В документах: Одня пятая доля. Три пятых доли. Семь пятых долей.
Как "одна зеленая пилюля", "три зеленых пилюли". "семь зеленых пилюлей".

Вопрос неоднократно обсуждался. К сожалению, правила склонения дробей (математических) не всегда возможно переносить на случаи юридического или нотариального употребления.

Что такое "три пятых яблока"? Это "три пятых [части] яблока". Здесь яблоко стоит в нужной форме, единой для всех случаев: семь десятых яблока, не "яблок". Но это только в математике.

В юридической практике "долей" называется совокупность ценностей (имущества), приходящаяся на одну условную единицу права собственника. Т.е. три пятых доли - это не кусочек доли в размером три пятых части. Это именно **три доли**. И здесь возникает другой принцип. "Три пятых [доли]" - это не дробь. Это три штуки объекта, называемого "пятой долей". И здесь невозможна интерпретация "три пятых [части]" доли [наследства]. "Часть" - это уже и есть доля.

Поэтому согласование идет не со знаменателем дробной части, а с количественным числительным:

Одна пятая доля [наследства].
Три пятых долей [наследства].
Семь двадцать пятых долей [наследства].

Поэтому и в предложном падеже:

***Наследник в одной пятой доле.

Наследник в трех пятых долях.

Наследник в семи двадцать пятых долях.***

и т. д.

Хотя лучше таких оборотов избегать вне юридического контекста: наследник "в доле" - это не всем понятно, а тут еще трудность с этой якобы дробью.

(+)
Ссылка на одно из предыдущих обсуждений.
[Склонение числительных](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27086/)

Я свою позицию не поменял ни на йоту.

(-----)

Переношу из комментариев, которые намерен удалить.

По поводу ответа Сержа и/или Граммы (пускай сам разбирается, где у него там кавычки).

Мне совсем не понравился ответ "Граммы", который Серж привел, не вникая. Там начали за здравие, согласившись с "Грамотой", а кончили за упокой, вывернув смысл наизнанку.

> Такой разнобой для юридического текст неприемлем, поэтому, очевидно, и был в качестве стандарта выбран единый вариант – "доли".

Это полная ерунда. Вариант "доли" не был принят в качестве стандартного, напротив, как следует из ответа "Грамоты", также процитированного Сержем/"Граммой" этот вариант был отвергнут, как противоречащий смыслу. 
А сама постановка вопроса об унификации согласований ради юридического текста просто фантастична для ресурса русского языка. По этому пути пойдя, придется найти единую форму для числительных: "одна квартиры", "две квартиры", "пять квартиры" ))). 
Т.е. отвечающий или не понял ни вопроса, ни проблемы, ни ответа "Грамоты" и/или сам плохо владеет русским.

Вот это мои претензии к ответу Сержа. Все остальное не имеет к академической сути вопроса никакого отношения.

Comment: behemothus, а чем закончился тогда ваш спор? Вы получили исчерпывающего ответа от Грамоты?

Comment: А при чем тут Грамота и завершение спора? Тоже мне авторитет.))) Нет, **исчерпывающего**, вроде, не получил.

Comment: понятно. ------

Comment: Семь пятых больше единицы, такое возможно? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, удалить мне свой ответ? Я просто засомневался в смысле долей, как только отправил его, но было уже поздно.(( Понял тогда, что, пожалуй, "доля" — это та же часть, а дробь от чего-то ещё. Но надеялся, что может всё-таки не так.

Comment: Про удалить ответ - не буду, естественно. А то, что больше единицы - это по контексту. В нотариальных делах - нет, понятно. Но это не грамматический запрет, а контекстный. Можно же представить себе текст типа ***"Согласно решению такого-то судьи,  Разэтакий Такой Сякоевич является наследником в семи пятых долях, что противоречит здравому смыслу"***.

Comment: Артем, с грамматической точки зрения ваш ответ верный. Именно родительный падеж советуют справочники. Остальное можете прочитать здесь [пять шестых доли или пять шестых долей?](http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4316&start=0&sid=7c0ab2888e861f0a61748cd54931ce04)[Склонение числительных](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27086) [Валгина. Современный русский язык](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/index.html?part-086.htm#i5963/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: Спасибо, Серж. Только по ссылкам я ничего не нашёл в пользу своего ответа. И сам плохо понимаю, при чём тут доля.(( Ведь действительно не от неё части, а от квартиры, наследства и т. д. А когда отвечал, плохо понял, о чём идёт речь.

Comment: Артем, я задал вопрос Грамме. ру. См. ответ.

Comment: Да, я его быстро проглядел, мне понравился, проголосовал. Потом повнимательнее перечитаю.

Comment: Артем, а как вы представляте формулировку, например, принципа наследования в равных  **долях**? Если убрать слова "доля", следуя горе-советчикам из "граммы"? Или, скажем, права собственности? Не надо в чужой монастырь со своим уставом ходить. Надо хотя бы разобраться...

Comment: Я в этом не разбираюсь, но, как я думаю, это что двое или несколько человек получают одинаковые части от квартиры (по площади, наверно). Нет?

Comment: А то, что по этой логике будет "одна квартиры", "две квартиры", "пять квартиры" — это ерунда!)) Ведь если простые дроби и десятичные, у которых произносишь десятые (в т. ч. и опуская слово "десятых", напр., *четырнадцать и три процента (14,3)*), согласуются только с родительным числом существительного (исключения с "половинами" только, где тот же род. п., только мн. ч., напр., *шесть с половиной батон**ов***), то с целыми числительными никто не заставит ставить существительные всегда, напр., в род. п. С какой стати-то?!

Comment: Нет. Отнюдь не ерунда. Читайте внимательно. ========= Например, при покупке/продаже 53/69 квартиры следовало бы, конечно, написать "покупатель приобрел пятьдесят три шестьдесят девятых долЕЙ", а при покупке 1/2 – "покупатель приобрел 1/2 долЮ". Такой разнобой для юридического текст неприемлем, поэтому, очевидно, и был в качестве стандарта выбран единый вариант – "доли". ======== Если единый вариант **доли** выбран (по мнению автора), для унификации, то и квартиры надо унифицировать, чем они хуже "долей"?!.

Comment: *согласуются только с родительным числом * Они не согласуются, они управляются. Пропущенным, но подразумеваемым **часть** (или как раз "доля") (***чего?***) процента, квартиры, яблока и т.д.  Вот откуда там родительный падеж. Но в любпм слкчае вы домысливаете. У автора ничего такого нет. Там сказано "для унификации". Точка. Других аргументов нет.  Но унифицировать - так все. Для удобства. Не находите, что остановится на долях глупо.

Comment: *Я в этом не разбираюсь, но, как я думаю, это что двое или несколько человек получают одинаковые части от квартиры (по площади, наверно)* Так, простите, Вы что, собираетесь для каждого объекта отдельный закон писать? Вы вслед за Сержем предлагаете отказаться от слова "доля". Ну вот есть закот, который гласит, что наследники первой очереди получают наследство в равных долях, за изъятием доли обязательного наследника (ну это очень условно, но смысл имеет).  Ну-ка сформулируйте мне это правило без cловa "доля" или "часть. ))))

Comment: В этом случае, наверно, и не надо отказываться от долей. Я имел в виду употребление долей только с числительными (дробями). То есть случай "m nn-ых долей **чего-то**". Вы пишете, что разнобой с падежами неприемлем, но, если б он был приемлем, я бы оставил разные падежи.

Comment: А вообще, чтобы это всё прочувствовать, надо не только чувствовать русский язык, но и быть юристом, хорошо знакомым с терминологией, или хотя бы приобрести приличный опыт в делах с наследством, имуществом и тому подобным. А у меня такого опыта совсем нет. Поэтому всё, что я предлагал, — это лишь скромные предположения того, как должно быть. Всё с припиской 'imho', уверенно судить я не берусь, конечно!

Comment: И конечно же, я вполне допускаю, что эти доли почему-то всё равно "нужны" и с дробями и другим существительным, просто я, возможно, не понимаю этих нюансов, из-за которых без них не обойтись.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, в одной пятой доле. Предложный падеж. Смотрите: пятая доля, нет пятой доли, ... думаю о пятой доле. Думаю, так понятнее.
То же и с тремя пятыми долями.

Comment: Niemand, вопрос спорный. В справочниках говорится, что при дробных числительных управляет дробь. Хотя ответ Грамоты.ру идет по этому вопросу не всегда совпадает со справочниками. Этот вопрос уже обсуждался на нашем форуме.

Comment: Ну, не надо путать одну пятую (чего?) добычи (например) и одну пятую долю (то есть часть).

Comment: А как скажете: две пятых доли/долей?

Comment: Ну, не надо путать одну пятую (чего?) - совершенно верно. Но 99 их ста - путают. Не только Серж, который, привычно смешивая два разных случая, говорит о "спорности". Рад, что вы это понимаете, я тут практически в одиночку бился со всем сообществом года два назад. – behemothus 7 минут назад

Answer (score 0):

### Ответ Граммы.ру

С одной стороны, мы абсолютно согласны с нашими коллегами с "Грамоты.ру" а таком их ответе:

> Вопрос № 273207
>
> как правильно писать "по 1/2 долИ или по 1/2 долЕ"

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Это непростой случай, от изменения окончания будет изменяться смысл.
>
> Доля = часть чего-либо. Например: доля наследства = часть наследства, доля квартиры = часть квартиры. 1/2 доля квартиры (одна вторая доля квартиры) = то же, что одна вторая часть квартиры, половина квартиры. По 1/2 доле квартиры (по одной второй доле квартиры) = по одной второй части квартиры, по половине квартиры. Например: при разводе каждый из супругов получает по одной второй доле квартиры (= по одной второй части, по половине, т. е. квартира делится между супругами пополам).
>
> 1/2 доли = одна вторая (чего?) доли, т. е. половина чьей-то доли (а сколько составляет сама доля – из этой формулировки неизвестно). По 1/2 доли квартиры (по одной второй доли квартиры) = по одной второй ОТ чьей-то доли, чьей-то части в этой квартире (а не по половине квартиры!).
>
> Надо сказать, что использование в юридических текстах формулировок 1/2 доля квартиры (дома и т. д.) существенно усложняет восприятие текста. Было бы лучше, если бы закрепилось написание 1/2 квартиры, 1/2 дома (т. е. слово *доля* здесь явно лишнее).

С другой же стороны, язык юридических документов справедливо стремится к стандартности формулировок – во избежание разночтений. Случай с 1/2 далеко не самый сложный. Например, при покупке/продаже 53/69 квартиры следовало бы, конечно, написать "покупатель приобрел пятьдесят три шестьдесят девятых долЕЙ", а при покупке 1/2 – "покупатель приобрел 1/2 долЮ". Такой разнобой для юридического текст неприемлем, поэтому, очевидно, и был в качестве стандарта выбран единый вариант – "доли".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37944/discussion-on-answer-by----).

Answer (score 0):

Ответ: Правопреемника в одной (пятой) доле наследства, в трех (пятых) долях наследства.

Мне кажется, что есть **очень простая** схема (может быть, условная) для составления таких словосочетаний,  при этом она одинакова как для математики, так и для юридических документов. Эта схема заключается в следующем.

В сочетаниях с дробями знаменатель дроби  – это порядковое числительное, поэтому мы считаем его  **о п р е д е л е н и е м**  и просто "пропускаем" при образовании  числового сочетания, которое строится по обычным правилам ( в одной доле, в трех долях). При этом существительное, доли которого считаются, всегда стоит **в Р.п.**

В общем виде мы имеем 4 слова: в трех пятых долях (П.п.) наследства (Р.п.),  но в математике одно или два слова пропускается: прибавить к трем пятым (долям целого числа), в трех пятых (долях) всех случаев.