# Как писать правильно: "по 1/3 доле" или "по 1/3 доли"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, редактура

> Приняли  в общую долевую собственность по 1/3 **доле** в праве собственности каждый на жилой дом.

или

> Приняли  в общую долевую собственность по 1/3 **доли** в праве собственности каждый на жилой дом.

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос: **Склонение математических дробей**. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420317/Склонение-математических-дробей

Answer (score 1):

Трудно понять. Предложение требует переделки. Смысл должен быть таков: доля каждого участника сделки в праве собственность на жилой дом равна 1/3 (одной трети).

Не "1/3 доли" (треть от доли) и не "1/3 доле". Последнее вообще не имеет смысла.

Пример исправления:

**Нижеподписавшиеся приняли жилой дом по адресу .... в общую долевую собственность, причем доля каждого подписанта в праве собственности на указанный дом равна 1/3.**

Для справки:

> Общая долевая собственность — это имущество, находящееся в общей собственности с определением доли каждого из участников и право сособственника на получение определенной доли доходов от пользования имуществом, а также его обязанность нести определенную долю расходов на содержание общего имущества.
>
> Доля выражается в виде дроби или процентов. Согласно п. 1 ст. 245 ГК доли участников предполагаются равными, если иное не вытекает из закона, договора или существа сложившихся между ними отношений.

([Гражданское право](http://www.allpravo.ru/library/doc99p0/instrum959/item1271.html))

Образец договора купли-продажи квартиры:

> 1.3. Объект приобретается в общую долевую собственность Покупателей: размер доли Покупателя 1 – 1/2, размер доли Покупателя 2 – 1/2.